# How to write a function to update linked list and print updated list?

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list

I have written a code to enter the name, age, department id, company name, and salary respectively, of employees from a text file into a linked list. I have made an insert function to insert employee details into a linked list and a display function to display the linked list. I need help in creating a function to add a new member to my list and print the new list. I'm having trouble understanding how to add a new node to the list and display the updated list (like what pointers to use..). I have already made a function for updatefile where Im asking for user input but I didnt call the function to the main yet. If someone can show me how to code it that will be a big help. Thanks!

Here are the details of the file, it is called employee.txt:

```
Peter 30 1001 Apple 8000
Joseph 50 1002 Oracle 4000
Mary 40 1003 Samsung 6000
Lilly 40 1203 Samsung 7000
Tony 50 1002 Oracle 3000
Jake 30 1005 Apple 3000
Sam 40 1007 Samsung 4000
Lisa 30 1300 Oracle 5000
Kate 50 1200 Apple 6000
Rick 50 1313 Apple 4000
```

My code :
'''

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    struct personTag {
        char name[20];
        int age;
    };

    struct officialTag {
        int deptId;
        char cmpName[20];
        double salary;
    };

    struct employeeTag {
        struct personTag personalInfo;
        struct officialTag officialInfo;
        struct employeeTag *next;
    };

    typedef struct employeeTag EmpTag;
    typedef EmpTag *EmpTagPtr;

    typedef struct personTag person;
    typedef struct officialTag official;


    void insert(EmpTagPtr *s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid, char E_cmpname[], double 
    E_salary);
    void displayEmployees(EmpTagPtr s);
    void updateFile(char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid, char E_cmpname[], double 
    E_salary);


    int main() {
        EmpTagPtr start = NULL;

        char E_name[20];
        int E_age;
        int E_deptid;
        char E_cmpname[20];
        double E_salary;

        // reading employee.txt file
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("employee.txt", "r");
        //fp = stdin;

        while (fscanf(fp, "%19s %d %d %19s %lf", E_name, &E_age, &E_deptid, E_cmpname, 
    &E_salary) == 5) 
        {
            insert(&start, E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
        }

        fclose(fp);



        displayEmployees(start);



        return 0;
    }

    void insert(EmpTagPtr *s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid, char E_cmpname[], double 
    E_salary) 
    {

        // create an empty node
        EmpTagPtr newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);

        // filling in the values
        strcpy(newNode->personalInfo.name, E_name);
        newNode->personalInfo.age = E_age;

        newNode->officialInfo.deptId = E_deptid;
        strcpy(newNode->officialInfo.cmpName, E_cmpname);
        newNode->officialInfo.salary = E_salary;

        while (*s && strcmp(newNode->personalInfo.name, (*s)->personalInfo.name) > 0) 
        {
            s = &(*s)->next;
        }

        // `s` now points at the `EmpTagPtr` pointer where the new node should be inserted:
        newNode->next = *s;
        *s = newNode;
    }

    void displayEmployees(EmpTagPtr s) 
    {
        EmpTagPtr current = s;

        while (current != NULL) {
            // printing the data part
            printf("Employee name:    %s\n", current->personalInfo.name);
            printf("Company name:     %s\n", current->officialInfo.cmpName);
            printf("Employee Age:     %d\n", current->personalInfo.age);
            printf("Department ID:    %d\n", current->officialInfo.deptId);
            printf("Employee Salary:  %.2lf\n", current->officialInfo.salary);
            printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
            current = current->next;  // move foward the current pointer
        }

        printf("NULL\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    void updateFile(char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid, char E_cmpname[], double E_salary)
    {

        // writing to employee.txt file
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("employee.txt", "w");
        //fp = stdin;

        printf("Enter Employee name :");
        scanf("%s",E_name);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Enter Company name  :");
        scanf("%s",E_cmpname);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Enter Employee Age  :");
        scanf("%d",&E_age);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Enter Department ID :");
        scanf("%d",E_deptid);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Enter Employee Salary :");
        scanf("%lf",E_salary);

        fclose(fp);
    }
```

'''

Comment: You seem to have working `insert()` and `displayEmployees()` so can you please update above  to clarify what your question is?

Comment: How do you suggest we "show you how to code it?" I surmise it will be similar to how you coded what you have already, but different. What is your actual *question*?  And fyi, this: `scanf("%d", E_deptid)` can't possibly work, nor can `scanf("%lf", E_salary);`, and your compiler should have told you why. Both are not providing proper addressing to `scanf`, and both invoke *undefined behavior* as a result.

Comment: @Allan Wind I want updateFile function to be able to request user input for employee name, company, salary, age, and Id and add those details to a newnode and link it to the existing linked list (I guess this also means I should write to my employee.txt file as well). I also want updateFile function to be able to print the updated linked list. Hope that clears it up! Can you teach me how to code it please?

Comment: `updateFile()`, you may have noticed, is very similar to your code in `main()`, so if want to add a new record then just call `insert()`. If you want to update an existing record write a `update()` function similar to your `insert()` except you now want to stop on a matching record (whatever that means, for example, the same name).  Once you write that function, you will find that your `insert()` and `update()` functions will be very similar.  Create a new question if you want help with writing out a file, it will similar to what you do in `main()` except you `fprintf()` instead of `fscanf()`.

Comment: @AllanWind I managed to inset details with your advice, I'm figuring out how to printout the updated details however, I tried calling the displayEmployees function after my update function but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: @on_my_puter how did you try calling it?

Comment: @MABisk I called the display function again right after calling I called the updatefile function. My updated code is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73278390/19677115

Comment: Please update this question with the current code if you need help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Allan_Wind suggested, I edited the `updateFile()` function as follows:

```
void update(EmpTagPtr *s) //Function declaration needs to be updated to.
{
    char E_name[20];
    int E_age;
    int E_deptid;
    char E_cmpname[20];
    double E_salary;

    // writing to employee.txt file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("employee.txt", "r+");
    // fp = stdin;

    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter Employee name :");
    scanf("%s", E_name);

    printf("Enter Company name  :");
    scanf("%s", E_cmpname);

    printf("Enter Employee Age  :");
    scanf("%d", &E_age);

    printf("Enter Department ID :");
    scanf("%d", &E_deptid);

    printf("Enter Employee Salary :");
    scanf("%lf", &E_salary);
    printf("\n");

    insert(s, E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fprintf(fp, "\n%s %d %d %s %.0lf", E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Since you didn't include freeing the allocated memory, I added the following function:

```
 void deallocateLinkedList(EmpTagPtr *listHead){
    while(*listHead != NULL){
        EmpTagPtr holder = *listHead;
        *listHead = (*listHead)->next;
        free(holder);
        holder = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will insert a new record into the memory backed list, but you want to use `fpritnf()` instead of `scanf()` to write out the file.  I suggest renaming the function to `update()` as you update both the in-memory linked list and the file.

Comment: @AllanWind You're right about the name, I changed it. Can you please explain what you meant regarding `fprintf()` and `scanf()`?

Comment: Never mind, I forgot the function both reads input from the user and writes it out.  You're good.