# Why is my print linked list function not working?

Tags: c, function, linked-list

I have written a code to enter the name, age, department id, company name, and salary respectively, of employees from a text file into a linked list. I have created 3 functions to insert, display and update the list. I'm having trouble with the updateFile function, the inserting values part is working but when I call the display function again (to print updated list) it's not working. Can someone help me out with this? thanks!

employee.txt (text file):

```
Peter 30 1001 Apple 8000
Joseph 50 1002 Oracle 4000
Mary 40 1003 Samsung 6000
Lilly 40 1203 Samsung 7000
Tony 50 1002 Oracle 3000
Jake 30 1005 Apple 3000
Sam 40 1007 Samsung 4000
Lisa 30 1300 Oracle 5000
Kate 50 1200 Apple 6000
Rick 50 1313 Apple 4000
```

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct personTag {
   char name[20];
    int age;
};

struct officialTag {
    int deptId;
    char cmpName[20];
    double salary;
};

struct employeeTag {
    struct personTag personalInfo;
    struct officialTag officialInfo;
    struct employeeTag *next;
};

typedef struct employeeTag EmpTag;
typedef EmpTag *EmpTagPtr;

typedef struct personTag person;
typedef struct officialTag official;


void insert(EmpTagPtr *s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid, char E_cmpname[], double 
E_salary);
void displayEmployees(EmpTagPtr s);
void updateFile(EmpTagPtr s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid, char E_cmpname[], 
double E_salary);


int main() {
    EmpTagPtr start = NULL;

    char E_name[20];
    int E_age;
    int E_deptid;
    char E_cmpname[20];
    double E_salary;

    // reading employee.txt file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("employee.txt", "r");
    //fp = stdin;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%19s %d %d %19s %lf", E_name, &E_age, &E_deptid, E_cmpname, 
&E_salary) == 5) 
    {
        insert(&start, E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
    }

    fclose(fp);

        int option;

    printf("(1) Display employee details\n");
    printf("(2) Add new employee to the record\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter an option : ");
    scanf("%d",&option);
    printf("\n");

    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
        displayEmployees(start);
        break;

        case 2:
        updateFile(start, E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
        displayEmployees(start);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void insert(EmpTagPtr *s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid, char E_cmpname[], double 
E_salary) 
{

    // create an empty node
    EmpTagPtr newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);

    // filling in the values
    strcpy(newNode->personalInfo.name, E_name);
    newNode->personalInfo.age = E_age;

    newNode->officialInfo.deptId = E_deptid;
    strcpy(newNode->officialInfo.cmpName, E_cmpname);
    newNode->officialInfo.salary = E_salary;

    while (*s && strcmp(newNode->personalInfo.name, (*s)->personalInfo.name) > 0) 
    {
        s = &(*s)->next;
    }

    // `s` now points at the `EmpTagPtr` pointer where the new node should be inserted:
    newNode->next = *s;
    *s = newNode;
}

void displayEmployees(EmpTagPtr s) 
{
    EmpTagPtr current = s;

    while (current != NULL) {
        // printing the data part
        printf("Employee name:    %s\n", current->personalInfo.name);
        printf("Company name:     %s\n", current->officialInfo.cmpName);
        printf("Employee Age:     %d\n", current->personalInfo.age);
        printf("Department ID:    %d\n", current->officialInfo.deptId);
        printf("Employee Salary:  %.2lf\n", current->officialInfo.salary);
        printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
        current = current->next;  // move foward the current pointer
    }

    printf("NULL\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void updateFile(EmpTagPtr s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid, char E_cmpname[], 
double E_salary)
{

    EmpTagPtr start = NULL;
    EmpTagPtr current = s;

    // writing to employee.txt file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("employee.txt", "a");
    //fp = stdin;

    printf("Enter Employee name :");
    scanf("%s",E_name);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Company name  :");
    scanf("%s",E_cmpname);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Employee Age  :");
    scanf("%d",&E_age);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Department ID :");
    scanf("%d",E_deptid);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Employee Salary :");
    scanf("%lf",E_salary);

    fprintf(fp, "%19s %d %d %19s %lf", E_name, &E_age, &E_deptid, E_cmpname, &E_salary);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: 'it's not working', well, a few more details might help, as well as what you found out while debugging.

Comment: Just a note in advance: Please don't `typedef` pointers! That's just information hiding without any further value.

Comment: `updateFile` writes to the file. It never adds anything to your internal list. I recommend you separate functionality, to create one function which read input, and creates an employee data structure and returns it. Then a which adds the structure you your internal list. And a third function which appends a structure to the file. Call these three in the order mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have type issue on `updateFile`, just activate compiler warnings. Your updateFile function is not updating `s`, you should add a node with the values:

```
insert(&s, E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
```

```
void updateFile(EmpTagPtr s, char E_name[], int E_age, int E_deptid, char E_cmpname[],-
double E_salary)
{

    EmpTagPtr start = NULL;
    EmpTagPtr current = s;

    // writing to employee.txt file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("employee.txt", "a");
    //fp = stdin;

    printf("Enter Employee name :");
    scanf("%s", E_name);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Company name  :");
    scanf("%s", E_cmpname);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Employee Age  :");
    scanf("%d", &E_age);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Department ID :");
    scanf("%d", &E_deptid);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Employee Salary :");
    scanf("%lf", &E_salary);

    fprintf(fp, "%19s %d %d %19s %lf", E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
    fclose(fp);
    insert(&s, E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
}
```

you can simplify the function signature using local variables

```
void updateFile(EmpTagPtr *s) {
    char E_name[20];
    int E_age;
    int E_deptid;
    char E_cmpname[20];
    double E_salary;


    // writing to employee.txt file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("employee.txt", "a");
    //fp = stdin;

    printf("Enter Employee name :");
    scanf("%s", E_name);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Company name  :");
    scanf("%s", E_cmpname);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Employee Age  :");
    scanf("%d", &E_age);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Department ID :");
    scanf("%d", &E_deptid);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Employee Salary :");
    scanf("%lf", &E_salary);

    fprintf(fp, "%19s %d %d %19s %lf", E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
    fclose(fp);
    insert(s, E_name, E_age, E_deptid, E_cmpname, E_salary);
}
```